# An error in aligning several systems of linear equations using systeme

Tags: equations, systeme

I have code to typeset four systems of linear equations.  I have all the equations aligned at the equals sign. In the first equation of the second system, I have

`+ 0 = (q-m)x + b_{1}`,

but I want

`0 = (q-m)x + b_{1}`,

and in the second equation of the second system, I have a gap between `y` and the equals sign.  In the first equation of the third and fourth systems, there is a gap between `x` and the equals signs.

Also, I would like to add a comma after the first three systems of equations and a period after the last system of equations.  I understand that `,` indicates a new equation within a `\systeme` command. So, I couldn't use `,` to have `LaTeX` typeset a comma within this environment.  Anyway, I would want these punctuation marks centered between the two lines in each system of equations.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\systeme{y = \mathrlap{qx + b_{1}}, y = \mathrlap{mx}} \\
\systeme{0 = \mathrlap{(q - m)x + b_{1}}, y = \mathrlap{mx}} \\
\systeme{x = \mathrlap{\dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}}, y = \mathrlap{mx}} \\
\systeme{x = \mathrlap{\dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}}, y = \mathrlap{\dfrac{mb_{1}}{m - q}}} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using four `systeme` environments, you could use four `array` environments embedded in an `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\bigg\{ \begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
y & qx + b_{1}\\y & mx 
\end{array},\\
&\bigg\{ \begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
0 & (q - m)x + b_{1}\\y & mx 
\end{array},\\
&\bigg\{ \begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
x & b_{1}/(m - q)\\y & mx
\end{array},\\
&\bigg\{ \begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
x & b_{1}/(m - q)\\y & mb_{1}/(m - q)
\end{array} .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Per your requst, here's a version of the system of equations that uses `\dfrac` macros instead of inline fractions for the final two systems. Because the curly braces in systems 3 and 4 are larger than those in systems 1 and 2, further horizontal spacing adjustments are also required to align the `=` symbols. (The need to perform horizontal spacing adjustments arises irrespective of whether `array` or `systeme*` environments are used.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mleftright} % "\mleft\{" avoids some spacing issues caused by "\left\{"
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\bigg\{ \begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
y & qx + b_{1}\\y & mx 
\end{array},\\
&\bigg\{ \begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
0 & (q - m)x + b_{1}\\y & mx 
\end{array},\\
&\Bigg\{ \mkern-1.7mu \begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
x & \dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}\\[1.5ex]y & mx
\end{array},\\
&\mleft\{ \mkern-3.2mu\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
x & \dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}\\[2.5ex] y & \dfrac{mb_{1}}{m - q}
\end{array} \mright. \,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Second Addendum*: If you really don't want to eyeball-adjust the horizontal alignment of the large curly braces relative to their associated two-line systems of equations (each of which is placed in an `array` environment), I can only suggest you place the four `array`s in the right-hand column of an "outer" two-column array: The left-hand column then contains the associated curly braces, sized via `\vphantom` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mleftright,array}

\begin{document}
%% First, define the four systems as arrays
\def\sysa{\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
             y & qx + b_{1}\\y & mx 
          \end{array}}
\def\sysb{\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
             0 & (q - m)x + b_{1}\\y & mx 
          \end{array}}
\def\sysc{\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
             x & \dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}\\[1.5ex] y & mx
          \end{array}}
\def\sysd{\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
             x & \dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}\\[2.5ex] y & \dfrac{mb_{1}}{m - q}
          \end{array}}

%% Second, place the systems in the right-hand column of an "outer" array
%% Each system array is featured twice: Inside a \vphantom statement in
%% the left-hand column, to determine the size of the curly brace, and 
%% again in the right-hand column as itself.
\[
\begin{array}{l@{}l}
    \mleft\{ \vphantom{\sysa} \mright. & \sysa \\[2.5ex]
    \mleft\{ \vphantom{\sysb} \mright. & \sysb \\[2.5ex]
    \mleft\{ \vphantom{\sysc} \mright. & \sysc \\[3.8ex]
    \mleft\{ \vphantom{\sysd} \mright. & \sysd 
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer your code.  May you give it to me with the the quotients typeset using the `\dfrac` commands?

Comment: @Adelyn - Done. Note that the use of `\dfrac` instead of inline fractions requires both vertical as well as horizontal spacing adjustments -- that's why I had posted the inline fraction version first... :-)

Comment: The punctuation in the middle of nothing looks really strange.

Comment: @egreg  It is grammatically correct to have the punctuation, and since I consistently use punctuation in equation environments and align environments, use of punctuation in Mico's display looks fine to me.  Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @Mico  I seem to remember that there is an artificial space of `\,` introduced using `\left\{` or `\left\(`, and that to compensate for this, a negative thin space command `\!` is used.  Is that right?  How did you decide to use `\mkern-1.7mu` to get consistent spacing?

Comment: @Mico  Why did you decide to use `\\[1.5ex]` to separate the two equations in the third system of linear equations and  `\\[2.5ex]` to separate the two equations in the fourth system of linear equations?

Comment: @Adelyn - On the choice of additional vertical spacing in systems 3 and 4: It's important to keep in mind that good typography requires making aesthetic choices, which are inherently personal. I chose 1.5ex for system 3 to make the vertical distance between the `=` symbols "not too jarringly different' from systems 1 and 2. For system 4, I chose 2.5ex because I thought it was important to keep the denominator of the upper fraction well separated from the numerator in the lower fraction. Interestingly, my choices of 1.5 and 2.5 are not all that different from egreg's choices of 1.75 and 2.25.

Comment: @Adelyn - On the *horizontal* spacing adjustments: The first three systems involve `\bigg` and `\Bigg` left curly braces, which do not insert whitespace on their *left*; that's why I suggest using `\mleft\{` rather than `\left\{` for the curly brace for system 4. Because the curly braces in systems 3 and 4 are taller than those in systems 1 and 2, they are also a bit wider, requiring some adjustment on their *right*. The adjustment directives `\mkern-1.7mu` and `\mkern-3.2mu` -- `\mkern-3mu` is equivalent to `\!`, by the way -- were chosen by eyeballing the results.

Comment: @Adelyn - For what it's worth, if you look closely at both of egreg's solutions, you'll notice that the `=` symbols in systems 3 and 4 are not perfectly aligned with those in systems 1 and 2; this is a consequence of the fact that the curly braces in systems 3 and 4 are (slightly) wider than those in systems 1 and 2. An spacing adjustment somewhere between `\mkern-1.5mu` and `\mkern-2mu` would seem necessary to bring about alignment of all four `=` symbols.

Comment: @Mico  After magnification, I do see that the brace in the fourth system of linear equations is slightly wider than the brace in the third system of linear equations, and that this latter brace is wider than the braces in the first two systems of linear equations.  Is it possible to use an `alignat*{2}` environment, and to have the last alignment marker `&` immediately preceding the `array` environment?  In this way, aligning the equals signs "by eyeballing" can be avoided.

Comment: @Adelyn - I don't think your idea (of avoiding eyeball-based horizontal adjustments) can be accomplished along the lines you suggest. I've edited my answer to provided a second addendum, in which I show how the idea may be implemented using nested `array` environments.

Comment: @Mico  I appreciate your efforts.  Your use the `array` environment within an `array` environment is illuminating.  (I really did not want to have to estimate every time I needed to typeset a system of linear equations.)

Comment: @Adelyn - You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and/or "Accept" the answer you find particularly helpful. ;-)

Comment: @user74973 You can only accept an answer when logged in with the account used to ask.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `\systeme*`, which doesn't do alignment. For the second, you also have to declare `0` as a variable. In the ones with the fraction I added a supplementary vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\systeme*{y = qx + b_{1}, y = mx} \\
&\systeme*[var=x,y,0]{0 = (q - m)x + b_{1}, y = mx} \\
&\syslineskipcoeff{1.75}\systeme*{x = \dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}, y = mx} \\
&\syslineskipcoeff{1.75}\systeme*{x = \dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}, y = \dfrac{mb_{1}}{m - q}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can improve the spacing and add punctuation (but I'd avoid commas and periods); for a comma, place it in braces, so it will be invisible to the equation scanner.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\systeme*{y = qx + b_{1}, y = mx{\;,}} \\
&\systeme*[var=x,y,0]{0 = (q - m)x + b_{1}, y = mx{\;,}} \\
&\syslineskipcoeff{1.75}\systeme*{x = \dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}, y = mx{\;,}} \\
&\syslineskipcoeff{2.25}\systeme*{x = \dfrac{b_{1}}{m - q}, y = \dfrac{mb_{1}}{m - q}{\;.}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The two `\dfrac`s in the final `systeme*` seem awfully close to each other.

Comment: @egreg  That is (almost) the display that I wanted.  How do I add the punctuation marks?

Comment: @egreg  Are you saying that `systeme` aligns at the left brace?  I think that I tried using it and there was no alignment with the left brace.

Comment: @egreg  You use `\syslineskipcoeff{1.75}` in both the third and fourth systems of linear equations.  The line separations appear differently, though.

Comment: @Adelyn I don't know where the commas should be placed, so I didn't add them. The systems are left aligned because of the `&` that precedes each one. The separation *is* the same in the last two systems, but the fourth has a taller second equation; increase the value.